# Issue when sending SMTP Emails

Tags: smtp

I am trying to send a mass mailing campaign using PHPList. I have everything working as I need but I am getting an error message from emails sent to Google.

This error occurs in the header of the message:

> Received-SPF: permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during lookup of bounce@planemover.com: exceeds recursive limit) client-ip=xxx.xx.xxx.xx;
>   Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
>          spf=permerror (google.com: permanent error in processing during lookup of bounce@planemover.com: exceeds recursive limit) smtp.mailfrom=bounce@planemover.com

Does anyone know what would cause this error? Will this error cause my domain to be blacklisted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the present time, the SPF record on your domain is:

> **planemover.com.**       3600    IN  TXT "v=spf1 mx a ip4:71.122.219.173 ip4:71.122.219.172 a:mx1.selling-ac.com include:selling-ac.com **include:planemover.com** ~all"

It contains an `include:` directive pointing back at itself. This will result in an infinite loop (or recursion).

You need to remove `include:planemover.com` from this DNS record. The TTL on this record is 3600 (or 1 hour), so it will take up to 1 hour after that change occurs on *all* of your hosting nameservers, for this to become effective globally.

Also, in the future, this kind of question is more appropriate for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). It's probably off-topic here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This helps point me in the right direction and I will be sure to use Server Fault next time. Thanks you the help.